# How to solve error when adding big number of tables

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have this Google Script where I am creating a document using a template table that lives in another document.

The new document will have a number of small tables (like cards) in it.
The code bellow works fine for 100, 200 tables and it finishes in less than 10 seconds. But it fails for more than 500 tables.
There is no error message in the Executions window.

I have tried the saveAndClose() function (commented out) but the error continues and it just takes longer to run.

I ran out of ideas how to fix that.
Any help or ideas will be appreciated.

```
function insertSpecification_withSection(){
  startTime = new Date()
  console.log("Starting Function... "); 
  
  // Retuns a Table Template Copied from another Document
  reqTableItem = RequirementTemplate_Copy();
  
  
  // Creates X number of separated tables from the template
  for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++){
    table = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().appendTable(reqTableItem.copy());

    //    if((i % 100) === 0) {
    //      DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().saveAndClose();
    //    }
    //    
    
  }
  endTime = new Date();
  timeDiff = endTime - startTime;
  console.log("Ending Function..."+ timeDiff + " ms"); 
  
}

function RequirementTemplate_Copy() {

  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  var ReqTableID = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('ReqTableID');
  try{
    var templatedoc = DocumentApp.openById(ReqTableID);
  } catch (error) {
    DocumentApp.getUi().alert("Could not find the document. Confirm it was not deleted and that anyone have read access with the link.");
    //Logger.log("Document not accessible", ReqTableID)
  } 
  var reqTableItem = templatedoc.getChild(1).copy();
  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  return reqTableItem
}
```

Comment: try `for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++){
    DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().appendTable(reqTableItem);
  }`  [mcve] should include `RequirementTemplate_Copy()`

Comment: I get the error: Element must be detached.

Comment: If I make ```for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++){     DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().appendTable(reqTableItem.copy());   }``` I still get the error

Comment: I don't see a method getChild() for Document Class [Document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document)

Comment: Body class has a getChild() method.  I your problem is in `RequirementTemplate_Copy()`

Comment: You are right, it was missing the getBody(). I don't know why it wasn't failing from the begining without it. but I added and the error persist. ```var reqTableItem = templatedoc.getBody().getChild(1).copy(); ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a long method chaining to append the tables inside the `for` loop, declare a variable for the document body before the `for` and use it inside the `for`. In other words,

**replace**

```
 // Creates X number of separated tables from the template
  for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++){
    table = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().appendTable(reqTableItem.copy());
```

**by**

```
 var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
 // Creates X number of separated tables from the template
  for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++){
    table = body.appendTable(reqTableItem.copy());
```

The above code was tested with the following template

[image]

The script finished without errors. The resulting document has 50 pages.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rubén, that's what I was doing in the principle. But it seems that it is a memory limit problem. Because exact same code fail if I make 1000 tables or if the tables has a couple more rows or data inside. Does it fail with you to?

Comment: At some point during the insertion I get the error "Exception: Service Documents failed while accessing document with id" while running it directly on script (before was an addon)

Comment: @CaueNapier Follow-up questions should be posted as new questions. If I you do it, please include a sample table and be clear about the number of tables to insert.

Comment: Thanks for explaining @Rubén, I have created a new question witth the details. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64835452/how-to-fix-service-documents-failed-while-accessing-document

Answer (score 1):

Just like mentioned in the other answer, it is best to save the document outside the loop and call it when needed. Same goes for the body of the document.

```
let currentDoc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
let bodyDoc = currentDoc.getBody();
for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++){
    table = bodyDoc.appendTable(reqTableItem.copy());
    //    if((i % 100) === 0) {
    //      currentDoc.saveAndClose();
    //    }
    //    
  }
```

**However**, since you are mentioning that you are receiving the `Exception: Service Documents failed while accessing document with id` error, you might want to take a look at this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158310285) on Issue Tracker **since what you are experiencing might be a bug** with Apps Script.

If this is the situation, I recommend you to star the issue and eventually add a comment saying that you are affected by it.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices).