# How to fix "Service Documents failed while accessing document" while inserting a lot of data?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

This is a follow-up question derivated from [How to solve error when adding big number of tables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64828185/1595451)

With the code below, I get the following message when, for 500 tables. BUt it works fine for 200 for example.
`Exception: Service Documents failed while accessing document with id`

The error happens on line 22, inside de if  `body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();`

You also have the table template id to try, but here is an image

[Image Table Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEJWB.png)

```
function RequirementTemplate_Copy() {
  var templatedoc = DocumentApp.openById("1oJt02MfOIQPFptdWCwDpj5j-zFdO_Wrq-I48mUq9I-w");

  return templatedoc.getBody().getChild(1).copy()
}


function insertSpecification_withSection(){
 
  // Retuns a Table Template Copied from another Document
  reqTableItem = RequirementTemplate_Copy();
  
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  // Creates X number of separated tables from the template
  for (var i = 1; i < 501; i++){
    table = reqTableItem.copy().replaceText("#Title#",String(i))
    body.appendTable(table);
    
    if((i % 100) === 0) {
      DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().saveAndClose();
      body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody()
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Usually the error message includes a code line number. Please add the complete textual error message

Comment: The error shows at line ```body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include on it all the relevant details. By the other hand I think that  you should not repeat the same content from the previous question. That make it view it as a duplicate instead as a follow-up question. On this site duplicate questions might be closed and include a link to a question that already has an answer.

Comment: Should I delete the previous question then?

Comment: It's worthy to note that line you are referring as the one that is causing the error is before the for loop, so it looks that the number of tables to insert is irrelevant.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify properly, the error happens on line 22, inside de if  ```body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();```

Comment: No, first because it already was answered, second because they are about different problems (the first one didn't show an error message and this is showing one, also the answer shows that the change suggested worked fine.

Comment: I am sorry about the mess. I am working on it for a quite while and I am a bit desperate and tired. The previous answer didn't get me somewhere new, the problem is the same. But I appreciate the answer and accepted it. Thanks =)

Comment: I suggest you to focus this question on debugging / finding the Google Apps Script "oddities"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that the error message isn't related to the number of tables to be inserted because it occurs before adding the tables.

Just wait a bit an try again. If the problem persist try your code using a different account if the code runs on the second account it's very possible that you first account exceeded a limit... there are some limits to prevent abuse that aren't published and that might change without any announcement.

---

Using the fix suggested for the code from [my answer to the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64829047/1595451) and changing the number for iteration limit to 1000 and 2000 works fine

The following screenshot shows the result for 1000

[image]

Here is the code used for the tests

```
 function insertSpecification_withSection(){
  startTime = new Date()
  console.log("Starting Function... "); 
  
  // Retuns a Table Template Copied from another Document
  reqTableItem = RequirementTemplate_Copy();
  
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  // Creates X number of separated tables from the template
  for (var i = 0; i < 2000; i++){
    table = body.appendTable(reqTableItem.copy());

    //    if((i % 100) === 0) {
    //      DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().saveAndClose();
    //    }
    //    
    
  }
  endTime = new Date();
  timeDiff = endTime - startTime;
  console.log("Ending Function..."+ timeDiff + " ms"); 
  
}

function RequirementTemplate_Copy() {

  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  var ReqTableID = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('ReqTableID');
  try{
    var templatedoc = DocumentApp.openById(ReqTableID);
  } catch (error) {
    DocumentApp.getUi().alert("Could not find the document. Confirm it was not deleted and that anyone have read access with the link.");
    //Logger.log("Document not accessible", ReqTableID)
  } 
  var reqTableItem = templatedoc.getChild(1).copy();
  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  return reqTableItem
}

function setReqTableID(){
  PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty('ReqTableID', '1NS9nOb3qEBrqkcAQ3H83OhTJ4fxeySOQx7yM4vKSFu0')
}
```

Comment: But if I had hit any limit, the code wouldn't be working every time I reduce the number of tables. It always work with 100 tables, for example.

Comment: If you use that same code and make the for loop with 2000 tables does it work for you?
```for (var i = 1; i < 2001; i++){```

Comment: I get the following error using exactly the same code you use. It might be something else with google.

```Too many changes applied before saving document. Please save changes in smaller batches using Document.saveAndClose(), then reopen the document with Document.openById().```

Comment: Please edit the question to include the error message, to add more details about your environment (type of goggle account used, age of the account , runtime used , country where you are, etc.), how many tests have you done, why you need to add so many tables,, the results that you got when running the code using another account,etc.,